# CKEditor selectionChange is not working as it should be

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I am using CKEditor as a part of my Python, Flask project. I am trying to pass text which is selected with mouse to another "textarea".

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>CKEditor Örneği</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.16.2/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <textarea id="editor1" name="editor1"></textarea>
    <br>
    <textarea id="selectedTextDisplay" name="selectedTextDisplay" readonly></textarea>

    <script>
        CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');
        
        function showSelectedText() {
            var editor = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1;
            var selectedText = editor.getSelection().getSelectedText();
            document.getElementById('selectedTextDisplay').value = selectedText;
        }

        CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.on('selectionChange', function (evt) {
            showSelectedText();
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

I have the code above, and the problem is that when I select a text, it doesn't directly pass it to other textarea. I have to click somewhere else in the editor, or switch between tabs or programs on my computer, and when I return to my webpage, then the copying process happens.

I have tried to use "mouseup" like this but did not help.

```
CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.on('mouse', function (evt) {
            showSelectedText();
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works (tbh, I'm cheating a bit).

```
CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.on('contentDom', function () {
  this.document.on('selectionchange', showSelectedText);
});
```

What this does is:

1. Wait for the CKEditor instance to initialize. It's kind of like `DOMContentLoaded`, but in this case it's referring to the loading of the content of CKEditor - it's actually creating an iframe, and populating it with content.
2. After the instance has been initialized, an event listener is attached to *its DOM*, and that event listener is doing what you want it to - monitor when the selection is changed. Also - notice the lack of capitalization in `selectionchange`. This is because I'm using the [`selectionchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/selectionchange_event) event from the [Selection API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection).

A working fiddle can be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ktcqepba/1/) (apologies for providing an off-site resource, but the stacksnippet was reporting CORS errors, and I didn't know how to overcome them).